# Display select element with option depending another select

Tags: angular, asynchronous, drop-down-menu, angular-ng-if

I have a select dropdown component with the @Input option variable.

I want to display options in another instance of this component based on what is selected in first

How to achieve this?

```
<select *ngIf="option=='city'" class="form-select border-blue" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option selected>Select City</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option>
</select>
```

My current "solution" is adding a select tag as a new element on new line , while i need dependant select element to be always on page and wait for first selection

```
<select *ngIf="selectedCity|async" class="form-select border-blue" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option selected>Select district</option>
    <option *ngFor="let dist of (districts|async)" value="{{dist}}">{{dist}}</option>
</select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5qthim?file=src/app/select-one/select.component.html

Comment: yeah thnx @Drenai, please see stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5qthim?file=src/app/select-one/select.component.html)  _italic_ **bold** `code`, so what i want is to have district select menu ALWAYS on screen with default selected option, and when i select a city districs will be populated in options

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution for me was quite simple,

1. I passed selected city to the parent component,
2. there passed it through function got array of districts for this particular city
3. Passed array of the districts from parent component to my select (child) component.

My mistake was that I was trying to achieve functionality from the select component itself.

If there is a way to do it with async pipe please share